# why is it that my script only uploads the last image to my ftp and database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image, upload

i have a uploading script and works like a charm but i wanted to expand it with not only uploading one image, but several images. That resulted in my script only uploading the last image and not all of them with the text included with them in the textarea. i just can't figure out why it just won't upload all images.

my upload.php:

```html
<?php // Start a session for error reporting session_start(); // Call our connection file require( "includes/conn.php"); // Check to see if the type of file uploaded is a valid image type function is_valid_type($file) { // This is an array that holds
all the valid image MIME types $valid_types=a rray( "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif"); if (in_array($file[ 'type'], $valid_types)) return 1; return 0; } // Just a short function that prints out the contents of an array in a manner that 's easy to read
// I used this function during debugging but it serves no purpose at run time for this example
function showContents($array)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
}
 
// Set some constants
 
// This variable is the path to the image folder where all the images are going to be stored
// Note that there is a trailing forward slash
$TARGET_PATH = "content/uploads/";
 
// Get our POSTed variables
$fname = $_POST['fname '];
$lname = $_POST['lname '];
$image = $_FILES['image '];
 
// Sanitize our inputs
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br($lname));
$image['name '] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name ']);
 
// Build our target path full string.  This is where the file will be moved do
// i.e.  images/picture.jpg
$TARGET_PATH .= $image['name '];

// Make sure all the fields from the form have inputs
if ( $fname == "" || $lname == "" || $image['name '] == "" )
{
    $_SESSION['error '] = "All fields are required";
    header("Location: indexbackup.php");
    exit;
}

// Check to make sure that our file is actually an image
// You check the file type instead of the extension because the extension can easily be faked
if (!is_valid_type($image))
{
    $_SESSION['error '] = "You must upload a jpeg, gif, or bmp";
    header("Location: indexupload.php");
    exit;
}

// Here we check to see if a file with that name already exists
// You could get past filename problems by appending a timestamp to the filename and then continuing
if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
{
    $_SESSION['error '] = "A file with that name already exists";
    header("Location: indexupload.php");
    exit;
}
 
// Lets attempt to move the file from its temporary directory to its new home
if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name '], $TARGET_PATH))
{
    // NOTE: This is where a lot of people make mistakes.
    // We are *not* putting the image into the database; we are putting a reference to the file's location on the server $sql="insert into people (fname, lname, filename) values ('$fname', '$lname', '" . $image[ 'name'] . "')"; $result=m ysql_query($sql)
or die ( "Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error()); header( "Location: indexupload.php"); exit; } else { // A common cause of file moving failures is because of bad permissions on the directory attempting to be written to // Make sure you chmod
the directory to be writeable $_SESSION[ 'error']="Could not upload file.  Check read/write persmissions on the directory" ; header( "Location: indexupload.php"); exit; } ?>
```

and this is the page that let's me select the files and fill in the text area:

```js
var abc = 0;      // Declaring and defining global increment variable.
$(document).ready(function () {
    //  To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed.
    $('#add_more').click(function () {
        $(this).before($("<div/>", {
            id: 'filediv'
        }).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>", {
            name: 'image',
            type: 'file',
            id: 'file'
        }), $("<br/><br/>")));
    });
    // Following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file.
    $('body').on('change', '#file', function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            abc += 1; // Incrementing global variable by 1.
            var z = abc - 1;
            var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
            $(this).before("<div id='abcd" + abc + "' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            $(this).hide();
            $("#abcd" + abc).append($("<img/>", {
                id: 'img',
                src: 'images/x.png',
                alt: 'delete'
            }).click(function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }));
        }
    });
    // To Preview Image
    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    ;
    $('#upload').click(function (e) {
        var name = $(":file").val();
        if (!name) {
            alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">
    <div id="formdiv">
        <h2>Upload en delete pagina</h2>
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
            echo "<span id=\"error\"><p>" . $_SESSION['error'] . "</p></span>";
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }
        ?>   
        <form action="upload2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Merk</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" style="width:250px;"/><br />

            <label>beschrijving</label>
            <textarea name="lname" style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea><br />

            <label>Upload afbeelding</label>
            <div id="filediv"><input type="file" name="image" id="file"/></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" />  
            <br /><br /><p>                    
                <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
                <br /><br /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" id="submit" class="upload" style="left:200px;"/>
            </p>
        </form>
        <br /><br />
        <p>
        <form action="delete_multiple.php" method="post">
            Wil je auto's van de site halen?
            <input type="checkbox" name="formverkocht" value="Yes" />
            <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks in advance guys!

Comment: remove the spaces from your keys first. `$_POST['fname '];`

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in **ALL** of your post parameters:

```
$fname = $_POST['fname '];
                      ^--
```

That space DOES count for naming purposes, and is NOT the same as `'fname'`. The keys in _POST/_GET must match EXACTLY what you have in the html:

```
<input type="text" name="foo">   -> $_POST['foo']  // note the LACK of a space
<input type="text" name="bar ">  -> $_POST['bar '] // note the space
```

Comment: don't you think its a foreach missing for images ?

Comment: I deleted my answer because i did mistake by putting everything in foreach.

Comment: what mutiple images? OP has only one file input in the code, and it's not named properly to submit multiple images as a single name anyways.

Comment: i have a javascript more files button that let"s you upload more images, but it choices to take only the last one to upload to the database and ftp

Comment: @fgod: yes, because you're not naming your inputs with `[]` to tell PHP to expect MULTIPLE different submissions with that name. `name="foo"` produces a SINGLE entry in _files/_post/_get. `name=foo[]` allows multiples

Comment: @MarcB should that be changed in the java script too?

Comment: probably. if you're duplicating that file element, then each has to have a UNIQUE name/id, or at least use the `[]` naming "hack". doesn't matter how/where that dupe comes from. you have to keep things consistent.

Comment: then you'll have to start debugging. e.g. `var_dump($_FILES)`. see what's coming in. fire up your browser's debugger and see what gets sent out on the wire.

Comment: @MarcB maybe a stupid question, but how do i do the debugging code and where do i implement it? (i'm a noob at php coding, so these things take time for me...)

Comment: put it at the top of your script: `<?php var_dump($_FILES); exit()`. If you don't see all your files there in the first place, then PHP isn't receiving them properly.

Comment: @MarcB with the entries changed to name="image[]" it does give me multiple files in the output:(array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "btn_1.gif" [1]=> string(9) "btn_5.gif" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "image/gif" [1]=> string(9) "image/gif" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(39) "/sites/mianautoservice.nl/tmp/php7elaa8" [1]=> string(39) "/sites/mianautoservice.nl/tmp/phpldheU5" } ["error"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(415) [1]=> int(333) } } }) but they don't get moved correct for upload i think